# Injecting data from component functions into Angular2 animations

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-animation

In angular 2 I am trying to use `@angular/animations` to make a component where a `<li>` element follows the mouse `(ondrag)` and stays in position after `(ondragend)`. I am quite new to angular and very lost on what the best way to tackle this problem is. I would like to be able to inject a string from my component back into the animations but am not sure if this is possible. See an example below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-test',
  template: `
  <li
  *ngFor="let letter of list"
  [@lettereState]="letter.state"
  (ondrag)="letter.toggleState(); mouseCords($event.clientX, $event.clientY);"
  (ondragend)="letter.toggleState()">
      {{letter}}
  </li> `,
  animations: [
    trigger('letterState', [
      state('active', style({
        transform: //'translate(Inject the cordinates here {mouseX}, {mouseY})',
      })),
    ])
  ],

})
export class LetterBankComponent {

  constructor(
  ) {}

  private list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  private mouseX = ''
  private mouseY = ''
  }
  mouseCords(x, y) {
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;
  }
```

Comment: see here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9668

Comment: You might find this an interesting watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh9wj-1p2BM Ironically titled Animation in angular 4.0.0 and tragically makes several references to "coming in 4.1". So maybe 4.2? Around the 6 minute mark the talk begins to discuss "input variables".

Comment: Thanks for that I guess I must wait. However on a whim I added a `[draggable]` to one of my divs and it works almost as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of injecting data into animations it is a feature request and coming soon maybe (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9668).  In terms of having a draggable element adding `[draggable]` to an element seems to solve this problem